# Horizontally Center JQuery Lightslider slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm using jQuery [lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html) which is working, mostly great. I'm using it in responsive mode but I can't get it to automatically adjust the margins so that the slides always fill the full width of the page. It's always left aligned.

It's especially obvious when you get down to one slide for a 320px screen and the single slide is stuck to the left. This is my setup:

```
var slider = $('#light-slider').lightSlider({
    loop:true,
    keyPress:true,
    pager:false,
    item:6,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    useCSS:true,
    controls: false,
    responsive : [
        {
            breakpoint:1160,
            settings: {
                item:5
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint:980,
            settings: {
                item:4
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint:766,
            settings: {
                item:3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint:600,
            settings: {
                item:2
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint:380,
            settings: {
                item:1
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I can't see any info in the docs that would help me achieve centering the content so I didn't know if there was another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fix I came up with. Not sure if it applies to all situations, but the idea is you can pass any class you want and adjust with css.

In your javascript

```
$('#light-slider').lightSlider({
    ...
    addClass: 'center-thumbs',
    ...
});
```

In your css

```
.center-thumbs .lslide {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```